# RedisCache : TTL updating on each hit instead of DAYS

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis

I'm trying to update a field in a cache object on each hit. Similar to rate limiting with a different purpose.

My Cache Object:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CacheDO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int simCount;
    Date date;
    int viewCount;
}
```

Cache Service:

```
public CacheDO updateCacheDO(boolean isDateToBeUpdated, Date date, int customerId, String customerIdStr) {
   CacheDO cacheDO = new CacheDO();
   byte[] valueInBytes = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().get((customerIdStr).getBytes());
   if(valueInBytes == null){
      return addCacheDO(customerId, customerIdStr);
   }
   CacheDO deserialisedCacheDO;
   try {
      ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(valueInBytes);
      deserialisedCacheDO = (CacheDO) new ClassLoaderObjectInputStream(CacheDO.class.getClassLoader(), byteArrayInputStream).readObject();
   } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
      LOGGER.error("Error deserializing object");
      throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(),e);
   }
   cacheDO.setAbc(deserialisedCacheDO.getAbc());
   if (isDateToBeUpdated) {
      cacheDO.setDate(date);
   } else {
      cacheDO.setDate(deserialisedCacheDO.getDate());
   }
   cacheDO.setViewCount(deserialisedCacheDO.getViewCount() + 1);
   Long ttl = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().keyCommands().ttl(customerIdStr.getBytes(), TimeUnit.DAYS);
   LOGGER.info("Updating cache for customer {} ", customerId);
   redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().set(customerIdStr.getBytes(), SerializationUtils.serialize(cacheDO), Expiration.from(ttl, TimeUnit.DAYS), RedisStringCommands.SetOption.SET_IF_PRESENT);
   return cacheDO;
}
```

On every hit, ttl decreases by 1 instead of decreasing per day. I'm unable to figure out what could be done here, please help me understand my mistake.